# How to remove the debug mode in release output on android with QT 5.2

Tags: android, qt

I'm looking for how to produce a file for android with qt without active debug mode, I used qt 5.2 for android.
The output file is named QtApp-debug.apk.
I do not set the project or to remove the debug mode in release mode.
any idea?
Thank.
extract from the output of compilation:

```
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for QtApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on            
-do-debug:
     [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
         [echo] Debug Package: E:\Projects\qtprojects\build-CalcNd-Android_pour_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build\bin\QtApp-debug.apk
```

Comment: in manifest you can set debugging false, I'm not sure how you will make manifest in qt..

Comment: I have to add this option does not change anything:<application android:debuggable="false"

Answer (score 5):

In Qt Creator go to Projects and select the Run option.

Expand the Deploy Configurations section and click Create in the Sign Package section to create a Keystore.

Turn on the "Sign package" checkbox and be sure to select the Certificate alias.

Build your package and it should have the -release.apk suffix.

NOTE: The sign package checkbox is OFF every time you open Qt Creator. So, be sure to go in and re-check the box to sign the package when you re-open or the -debug.apk will mysteriously return!

Comment: hello, this solution works in English not locally (french) what was the source of my problem. look https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-10944

Comment: Location has changed into Build -> Build Android APK -> Sign Package

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to the problem.
The file is generated in release mode with the trousseau of keys file, as soon as you change something in the project, QtCreator no longer generates a file in release mode but in debug mode.
It is then re-file a trousseau of keys with identical elements.